# Get rows based on minimun values of the column after group by

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry about my question, but I tried some solutions but I couldn't the right answer. I'm  working with the Airbnb Boston data base and I would like to groupy by **listing_id** in the calendar data base and after to get the rows with minimum **price** and **price** different from **0.0**.

[image]

The data base has 1308890 rows and 4 columns. There are 3585 unique **listing_id**.

```
dfc_calendar[(dfc_calendar['available'] == True)].groupby('listing_id')['price'].min()
```

Using **isin** commando comparing **listing_id** take a long period and stops with error after a long period. When I try to get the indexes after the **groupby** I got **listing_id** values and I need the indexes of the rows. How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please see my attempt . Happy to clarify or help if more is needed

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as a clear example of the current and expected output. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I got you. Shout if I got it wrong because I am not clear what difference with 0.0 means
Data

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'listing_id':['12345','12349','12345','12349','12345'], 'Price':[3,5,67,7,12]})
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/2/2020', periods=len(df), freq='D')
df
```

Can go

```
df.groupby('listing_id')['Price'].min()
```

Or

```
df['MinPrice']=df.groupby('listing_id')['Price'].transform('min')
df
```

If you wanted to add availability in grouping. please try
df['MinPrice']=df.groupby('listing_id', 'available')['Price'].transform('min')
    df
Or

```
df.loc[df.groupby('listing_id')['Price'].idxmin()]
```

Comment: Thank you! This way you did is equal result I got. I would like to get all information of the row related with the smallest prices, like date, for example.

Comment: Did you mean df.loc[df.groupby('listing_id')['Price'].idxmin()]